# Center columns next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap, I have 3 unordered list items and with list items in them, I am trying to center the 3 Columns next to each other, so 
left align 
center
right align

I have them in the correct positions they are arranged correctly as of now but they are not next to each other they are on the top, bottom, and middle of the page. I have tried many things so far with no success.

```
<div class="container">



        <div class="colmask">
            <div class="box box_1">
              <div class="text-left">
                <h4>Left col</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="item 1">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="item 2 >Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>


<div class="text-center">
                <h4>Center col</h4>
                <ul>
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="item 1">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="item 2 >Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </ul>

<div class= "text-right">
                <h4>Right col</h4>
                <ul>
              <li><a href="item 1">one</a></li>
                 <li><a href="item 2 >Two</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `"` on both of your `item 2` elements and also have an erroneous `</ul>` in the second group. But we can't possibly answer this without your CSS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another class next to container and try to make the class have the property of display:inline-flex

you probably might have display:block that's why it is placed in top, middle and bottom.

Comment: Yes that was it I was using block, the only issue I am facing now is the spacing they are all close together.

Comment: You should probably make another class for each of the divs inside the container, set their width to 25-30% AND/OR check the margins and change the margins to see if it works

Answer (score -1):

Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet
    
    
    Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet